# Using RXJS 5 for Paginating a Search

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm trying to paginate a search and I need to prevent it from concatenating the list of results from the previous search.

Ex Search: %Dog%

1st page of results:
"Dog Barks", "Dog Growls", "Dog Itches"

2nd page of results:
"Dog Barks", "Dog Growls", "Dog Itches", "Dog Jumps", "Dog Eats", "Dog Sits"

Ex Search: %Cat%

1st page of results:
"Cat Meows", "Cat Itches", "Cat Runs"

2nd page of results:
"Cat Meows", "Cat Itches", "Cat Runs", "Cat Jumps", "Cat Eats", "Cat Sits"

Code:

```js
const offsetId$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);
const fooBar$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);

const observable = Rx.Observable
    .combineLatest(offsetId$, fooBar$)
    .startWith([])
    .switchMap(([offsetId, fooBar]) => fooBarCollection.find({
        fooBar: new RegExp("^" + fooBar, "i")
    }, {
        skip: offsetId * 200,
        limit: 200
    }).debounce(() => Rx.Observable.timer(10)))
    .scan((acc, value) => acc.concat(value));
    
observable.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: What output do you want? Maybe just remove `scan` where you do the `concat` if you don't want to concatenate the current value to the previous ones.

Comment: The output I need is in the question. I'm basically doing an infinite scroll with a searchbar. When you scroll down the results should be concatenated to the previous results, but when you do another search it should clear the values not concatenate them.

Comment: Yeah I think so, thanks @fridoo